# Python IndexError: list

Tags: python, read-write, index-error

I'm trying to execute a python program to read user input into a file and then process the file. The output of the file is as shown below:

Quantity|Price|Item

1|166.89|AMD Ryzen 5 3600 3.6 GHz 6-Core Processor

1|149.99|Asus PRIME X570-P ATX AM4 Motherboard

2|79.99|G.Skill Ripjaws V 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3600 CL16 Memory

1|179.97|Phanteks Eclipse P300A Mesh ATX Mid Tower Case

1|140.03|ADATA XPG CORE Reactor 650 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply

1|115.98|Silicon Power A60 1 TB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive

The code i'm trying to execute is given below:

```
    import os
    
    def order():
        orderName = input('What would you like to call this order? :')
        print(""" Please place your order below. 
              To stop Placing your order, leave the item name empty. """)
    
        item = input("Item: ")
        price = input("Price: ")
        quantity = input("Quantity: ") #gets all the info they want to add
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
    
        with open("mypc.txt","a") as a_file:
            a_file.writelines(quantity + "|" + price + "|" + item + "\n")
            a_file.close()
            print('Order saved to ' + orderName + '.txt. Exiting Application...')
    
        with open('mypc.txt','r')as Task2:
            print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format("\nQuantity","Price","Item Name"))
            for row in Task2:
                row=row.strip()
                eachItem=row.split("|")
                print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(eachItem[0],eachItem[1],eachItem[2]))
        print()
    
    
    
    def reciept():
        orderProcess = input('What Order would you like to Process? :')
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
        print("Going to the shops and buying eveything for you. Please hold. ")
    
    #this is the menu. this is where the user will make choices on what they do
    
    def menu():
    
    # Check if file exists
    if os.path.isfile('C:\\users\\Chandra\\Desktop\\mypc.txt')==False:
        # Create it and promptly close it, so it is in the correct location
        task1 = open('C:\\users\\Chandra\\Desktop\\mypc.txt','w')
        task1.close()
    
    # Open for read-write
    task2 = open('C:\\users\\Chandra\\Desktop\\mypc.txt','r+')
    
    # splits for new line break, making an array
    info = task2.read().split("\n")
    
    # Check to see if the file is empty
    if len(info) != 0:
        print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format("\nQuantity",
                                                        "Price",
                                                        "Item Name"))
        # Read each line of document
        for line in info:
            eachItem = line.split("|")
            print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(eachItem[0],
                                                           eachItem[1],
                                                           eachItem[2]))
    else:
        print('You have no items listed!')
    
    print("\n")
    
    
    print(""" Welcome to the Crapple Order Management System. You can
            1. Place an Order
            2. Process an Order
            """)
    option = int(input("What would you like to do? (Select 1 or 2) : "))
    
    if option==1:
        order()
    elif option==2:
        reciept()
    
    menu()
```

When I run the python script, I'm getting the below error:

```
    Quantity               Price                   Item Name
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Order_Process.py", line 77, in <module>
        menu()
      File "Order_Process.py", line 58, in menu
        eachItem[1],
     **IndexError: list index out of range**.
```

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: it means there aren't that many items in the list

Comment: Yes Derek.. I'm trying to create the file with the details and then later on process it. So, is there something wrong in my code which is causing this issue? I want to ask the user the choice of his option in menu() and then if he selects option 1.. get the user inputs into a file till he enters a null value and save it as mypc.txt file.

Comment: seems you are generating eachItem by spitting a line by `'|'`, if the resulting list is only 1 element long, then the problem would be that the line doesn't have that character in it

Comment: When you are writing a line in 'mypc.txt' you are adding an empty line, so when you open it for reading you got the first line with info and the second empty line. Just remove empty lines from info.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino - Thanks for the reply.Can you please point the change in the code? It would be very helpful then.

Comment: Make the following change: a_file.writelines(quantity + "|" + price + "|" + item + "\n") ------>  a_file.writelines(quantity + "|" + price + "|" + item). Or after 'for line in info:' palce an if condition if len(line) != 0

Answer (score 0):

You have empty lines in your data file.

```
import os


def order():
    orderName = input('What would you like to call this order? :')
    print(""" Please place your order below.
            To stop Placing your order, leave the item name empty. """)

    item = input("Item: ")
    price = input("Price: ")
    quantity = input("Quantity: ")  # gets all the info they want to add
    print("-----------------------------------------------")

    with open("mypc.txt", "a") as a_file:
        a_file.writelines(quantity + "|" + price + "|" + item + "\n")
        a_file.close()
        print('Order saved to ' + orderName +
              '.txt. Exiting Application...')

    with open('mypc.txt', 'r')as Task2:
        print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(
            "\nQuantity", "Price", "Item Name"))
        for row in Task2:
            row = row.strip()
            eachItem = row.split("|")
            print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(
                eachItem[0], eachItem[1], eachItem[2]))
    print()


def reciept():
    orderProcess = input('What Order would you like to Process? :')
    print("-----------------------------------------------")
    print("Going to the shops and buying eveything for you. Please hold. ")

# this is the menu. this is where the user will make choices on what they do


def menu():

    # Check if file exists
    if os.path.isfile('mypc.txt') == False:
        # Create it and promptly close it, so it is in the correct location
        task1 = open('mypc.txt', 'w')
        task1.close()

    # Open for read-write
    task2 = open('mypc.txt', 'r+')

    # splits for new line break, making an array
    info = task2.read().split("\n")

    # Check to see if the file is empty
    if len(info) != 0:
        print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format("\nQuantity",
                                                       "Price",
                                                       "Item Name"))
        # Read each line of document
        for line in info:
            if line.strip():

                eachItem = line.split("|")

                print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(eachItem[0],
                                                               eachItem[1],
                                                               eachItem[2]))
    else:
        print('You have no items listed!')

    print("\n")

    print(""" Welcome to the Crapple Order Management System. You can
            1. Place an Order
            2. Process an Order
            """)
    option = int(input("What would you like to do? (Select 1 or 2) : "))

    if option == 1:
        order()
    elif option == 2:
        reciept()


menu()
```

You need to loop:

```
import os


def order():
    orderName = input('What would you like to call this order? :')
    print(""" Please place your order below.
            To stop Placing your order, leave the item name empty. """)

    item = input("Item: ")
    if item == '':
        return
    price = input("Price: ")
    quantity = input("Quantity: ")  # gets all the info they want to add
    print("-----------------------------------------------")

    with open("mypc.txt", "a") as a_file:
        a_file.writelines(quantity + "|" + price + "|" + item + "\n")
        a_file.close()
        print('Order saved to ' + orderName +
              '.txt. Exiting Application...')

    with open('mypc.txt', 'r')as Task2:
        print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(
            "\nQuantity", "Price", "Item Name"))
        for row in Task2:
            row = row.strip()
            eachItem = row.split("|")
            print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(
                eachItem[0], eachItem[1], eachItem[2]))
    print()


def reciept():
    orderProcess = input('What Order would you like to Process? :')
    print("-----------------------------------------------")
    print("Going to the shops and buying eveything for you. Please hold. ")

# this is the menu. this is where the user will make choices on what they do


def menu():

    # Check if file exists
    if os.path.isfile('mypc.txt') == False:
        # Create it and promptly close it, so it is in the correct location
        task1 = open('mypc.txt', 'w')
        task1.close()

    # Open for read-write
    task2 = open('mypc.txt', 'r+')

    # splits for new line break, making an array
    info = task2.read().split("\n")

    # Check to see if the file is empty
    if len(info) != 0:
        print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format("\nQuantity",
                                                       "Price",
                                                       "Item Name"))
        # Read each line of document
        for line in info:
            if line.strip():

                eachItem = line.split("|")

                print('{0:<19}     {1:<19}     {2:<19}'.format(eachItem[0],
                                                               eachItem[1],
                                                               eachItem[2]))
    else:
        print('You have no items listed!')

    print("\n")

    print(""" Welcome to the Crapple Order Management System. You can
            1. Place an Order
            2. Process an Order
            """)


def main():

    ans = ''

    while ans != '0':

        menu()
        option = input("What would you like to do? (Select 1 or 2) : ")

        if option == '1':
            order()
        elif option == '2':
            reciept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But the code is getting input only once and then exiting. I need the code to accept the values till I enter a null value in the Item. Can you please help me with the code change? thanks.

Comment: You need to write a loop in the main function. When you read an item name, check if it is empty and return from the function. Otherwise, read other fields.

Comment: You open the file so many times. You should clean up the code. So it opens the file at the beginning. Move file reading out of the menu function.